# Como retornar dados de um Jason, dentro do PHP, via JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tendo dificuldades para retornar informações via Ajax. Ele tem que mostrar os resultados num `alert()`. O problema é que estou tentando retornar esses dados de um arquivo PHP que cria um `array()` e depois usa o `json_encode()`, mas na hora de retornar esses dados, ele retorna como objeto.

```php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    
$placa = array(

    'marca' => "Chevrolet",
    'modelo' => "Agile LTZ 1.4",
    
);

echo json_encode($placa);
```

Arquivo Js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#form-placa").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#placa").blur(function() {
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url : 'funcoes/placa.php',
        data: $('#form-placa').serialize(),
        
        beforeSend: function(){
            //$("#include").css('display', 'none');
            //loading.css('display', 'block');
        },
        
        success: function(dados){
        
            var carro = JSON.parse(dados); 
            
            alert(carro.marca);

            
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Nas Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor do navegador, na aba Rede, qual é a resposta que tem do seu PHP? (Pode fazer o teste usando um cliente HTTP, como o software Postman)

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo o `json.parse()` de algo que já é json. Pode usar o `jsonRESPONSE.dados no javascript` que será json. Pode abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e meter um breakpoint na resposta do ajax e ver se a resposta já vem como json(como você está a fazer o `json_encode()` no controller ele já vem como json.)